# java.util.Date cannot be cast to Object[]

Tags: java

I'm using java reflection to call methods at runtime. How do I cast a date object into an object array?

ie,

```
Method m = ....;
Object[] result = (Object[]) m.invoke(...);

public Date getDate() {
   return new Date();
}
```

Would give:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

**Edit**: yeah, I should just add it to an Object array instead and return it.

Comment: You can't cast a `Date` into an `Object[]`. Do you mean you wish to add it to the array?

Comment: Yeah, I need to return an array of Objects. In this case, I want the Date converted into an object and returned in an Object array of size 1.

Comment: Why would you think a single object could be an array?  What you cant to do isn't casting, it's wrapping.

Comment: Then you have to return a new `Object[]{new Date()}` from the `getDate` method, or wrap the returned value `new Object[]{m.invoke(...)}`.

Comment: Why do want to cast a Date into an Object array? This should not be possible. A Date **is** an Object (since it inherits from it) but it cannot be converted into an array of Objects.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to as invoke is a varargs method. you can do.

```
 Object result = method.invoke (instance , new Date ());
```

There is no need to create an array.

If it's the result you want to change you can wrap it, but I suspect there is no real need to do this. I would see if you really need an array